# Scrolling of GridView on Windows Store Apps

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have the following design concept for a Windows Store App, but I'm stuck at the best way to implement this:

[image: Initial view when page is loaded]

The red rectangle indicates the view of the page on an actual device. The page consist of a header `Grid` on the left, and a `GridView` on the right. What I want to achieve is, when the user performs a swipe gesture, instead of scrolling on the GridView, I hope that the entire page is scrolled, just like this:

[image]

I have managed to achieve this by using the following method:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
      <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="600" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid x:Name="LeftHeaderPanel" />
          <GridView Grid.Column="1"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" />
      </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, for some reason unknown to me, the `GridViewItems` within the `GridView` are displayed like a `StackPanel` after I set it this way, which means that the items no longer stack horizontally -- instead they now stacked vertically.

I have also discovered that by setting the `Height` attribute on the `GridView` control will solve the problem, but I'm trying to avoid the need to explicitly specify the height of my control. Is there any way out? Thanks!

Comment: How you defining `DataTemplate` for `GridViewItems` ? Show your xaml code

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `DataTemplate`, I am not defining anything, the same issue will occur if I manually placed 10 `<Grid Width="300" Height="300" />` items in the GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : below code works for me

**Use HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and  VerticalScrollBarVisibility instead of HorizontalScrollMode VerticalScrollMode**

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="600" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="LeftHeaderPanel" />
            <GridView Grid.Column="1"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
        </Grid>
 </ScrollViewer>
```